# creating a zip archive with txt files with content having utf-8 character set

Tags: java, utf-8, stream, zip

I have several strings (Json objects) that I want to write to a zip archive. The content should have UTF-8 character set. I could first create txt files on the hard disk and then zip them together. But is it also possible to create a zip archive directly with the txt files and the utf-8 character set?

At the moment I'm writing the bytes of the strings directly into the archive. And get the system's character set.

```
String str = "...";

ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("dest\\zipFile.zip"));

zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("entryName"));
zipOutputStream.write(str.getBytes());

zipOutputStream.close();
```

Comment: The text file would be the `ZipEntry`. As for using UTF-8, see [`String#getBytes(Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)) and [`StandardCharsets.UTF_8`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8).

Comment: `UTF-8` is a default charset when calling `public ZipOutputStream(OutputStream out)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what your doing seems right to me.

If you want to right multiple files then call `.closeEntry()`, and then you can add a new file using `putNextEntry` and `write` and as entry name use your file name.

For character encoding you could use something like this:

```
    ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(zipStream, Charset.forName("YOUR_WANTED_CHARSET"))
    );
```